# DELETE method with a payload using Ruby Rest:Client?

Tags: ruby, rest, rest-client

While I don't think it is very restful to have to include a payload in a DELETE request. I ran into an instance where I am testing a service that requires a payload for DELETE. Might there be a way using Ruby's Rest Client to accomplish this? Unfortunately, I am having a hard time with this one.

```
@json_request = '{"user_id": 5, "meta_data": "foo"}'
resource = RestClient::Resource.new "http://www.foo.com/some/process"
@response_update = resource.delete(@json_request, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
```

Output:
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not possible with that gem. You can see a PL addressing that. Maybe you could fork it and pull those changes to your own fork of the rest-client gem.

The pull request https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/pull/98

Answer (score 1):

Try this

RestClient::Request.execute(:method => 'delete', :url => "http://www.foo.com", :payload => json_data)

Answer (score 0):

As a very modern update, from the [ReadMe](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/README.md)

```rb
    RestClient::Request.execute(method: :delete, url: 'http://example.com/resource',
                                payload: 'foo', headers: {myheader: 'bar'})
```